# How to trim letter/characters off the end of a cell entry

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, libreoffice

I have entries in cells like this:

```
75864543&m
2211842
1523674&mr
3452435tr
```

The cells have varying numbers of numeric values, and some have characters/letters at the end. I want to trim everything off except numeric values, but am stuck due to the varying length of number values.

Does anyone have a workaround?

Comment: I have about 20,000 rows of data... Would this still work?

Comment: I'll be using other columns for this process and it seems to overload my word processor. Is there a formula to trim at the first instance of a non-number? I'd like to keep this in my spreadsheet if possible :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming between 1 & 9 digits at the start of the data (adjust as required) you can use this formula

`=LOOKUP(10^10,LEFT(A1,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9})+0)`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following User Defined Function:

```
Public Function ReturnNumerals(rng As Range) As String
    Dim sStr As String, i As Long, sStr1 As String
    Dim sChar As String
      sStr = rng.Value
      For i = 1 To Len(sStr)
        sChar = Mid(sStr, i, 1)
        If sChar Like "[0-9]" Then
          sStr1 = sStr1 & sChar
        End If
      Next
    ReturnNumerals = sStr1
End Function
```

**EDIT #1**:

If you are "macrophobic" or VBA is ruled out for other reasons, Then try this array formula:

=MID(SUMPRODUCT(--MID("01"&A1,SMALL((ROW($1:$300)-1)*ISNUMBER(-MID("01"&A1,ROW($1:$300),1)),ROW($1:$300))+1,1),10^(300-ROW($1:$300))),2,300)

Array formulas must be entered with **CNTRL-SHFT-ENTER** rather than just the **ENTER** key!

For example, if A1 contains:

a123wer98bg5

the ugly array formula will return:

123985